# New Relic shows increased web external lags, how to debug?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, newrelic

[image]

As you can see, suddenly the web_external response time spiked and remained high since (this is from ~20 hours ago).

Digging in new relic shows curl_multi_exec as the source of the issue.
curl_multi_exec is used by the AWS API but I dont see any difference between the previous condition and current one. and cant find an explanation for this. The throughput didn't change from previous days.

How can I further debug to find the problem ?

The system is PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.21 on EC2

Comment: actually the full version of the newrelic account is able to localize the issue the the certain PHP script or function.

Comment: I'm using the full version. It shows that curl_multi_exec causes it but no further details that I could find.